# Are these resistors parallel?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I am wondering whether, when analyzing this circuit, $R2$ and $R3$ can be treated as being in parallel and combined into an equivalent resistor. My issue is that it seems to me that they are parallel from the POV of the current coming out of $V1$ but they won’t be from the POV of the current coming out of $V2$. Also is the current coming out of V2 going to even go through any resistor or just head to the ground of $V1$?

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: What do you mean by "from the POV of the current"? The two resistors will have the same voltage, so they're in parallel.

Comment: Related - [Is there more than one legitimate way to determine whether resistor are in series or parallel?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/506964/is-there-more-than-one-legitimate-way-to-determine-whether-resistor-are-in-serie/507027#507027)

Comment: Don't talk about current "coming out" of a voltage source. Current _flows through_ a voltage source just like how it flows through any other two terminal component. Current can only ever flow in loops. The current flowing in to one side of the voltage source must always be equal to the current flowing out of the other side. Also, don't assume that you know which direction the current actually will flow. It could flow either way (or not at all) in a circuit that has more than one voltage source.

Comment: Don't talk about current "flowing to ground." There is no ground in your circuit. If you wanted a ground, you could add one—choose any node in your circuit (any wire) and call it "ground." But that would not change how the circuit behaves. "Ground" is just an arbitrary node that we use for reference when measuring voltage at other points in the circuit. _It's customary,_ in a circuit with a single power supply, to call the negative terminal of the supply "ground," but that's _only_ a custom, not a law. And, in a circuit like yours with more than one source, the choice is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the wires running to resistors are "ideal" (aka no voltage drop in them), the wire connecting the top of resistors R2 and R3 is all at the same voltage.  In addition, the wire connecting the bottom of resistors R2 and R3 is at the same (and different) voltage.  Since the voltage drop across R2 and R3 is the same, they are in parallel.